# How to inject dependencies in directive controller in following way?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-directive

I am using `ng-strict-di` mode in my angular app. It throws an error

`throbberController is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode`

my code is:

```
app.directive('throbberDirective', 
[   
    '_$ajax',
    function(_$ajax){
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            templateUrl: "common/utils/throbbers/throbber.html",
            controller: throbberController
        }
        function throbberController($scope){
            $scope.throbber = _$ajax.getThrobberConfigs();
            $scope.throbber.templateName = $scope.throbber.templateName;

        }
        throbberController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    }
]);
```

How to inject explicitly? Am I doing anything wrong? Help me solve this.

Comment: Try separating the directive and it's controller into two separate files. Then you can do injection like you normally would, in the controller.

Comment: Why it is not happening here?

Answer (score 1):

```
app.directive('throbberDirective', 
[   
    function(){
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            templateUrl: "common/utils/throbbers/throbber.html",
            controller: throbberController
        }
    }
]);
app.controller('throbberController', throbberController);
throbberController.$inject = ['$scope', '_$ajax'];
function throbberController($scope){
     $scope.throbber = _$ajax.getThrobberConfigs();
     $scope.throbber.templateName = $scope.throbber.templateName;

}
```

Comment: Why the previous process of mine has failed?

Comment: `throbberController.$inject = ['$scope'];` in this line `throbberController is undefined`